# Node.js: выполнение кода по расписанию

Tags: node.js, события, schedule

### Ситуация:

Нужно выполнять один скрипт по определенному рассписанию (например каждый день в 15:00 кроме выходных). Я смотрел документацию и модули в npm, но что-то не нашел вообще никаких вариантов решения этой проблемы кроме выполнения кода через какой-то промежуток времени (но это вообще ну вариант).

### Вопрос:

Существует ли нативный способ решения этой проблемы? Или же есть какой нибудь npm модуль у которого есть такой функционал?

Comment: А может всё-таки cron?

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо. Как раз то что я искал.

Answer (score 0):

**Можно так:**

1. Если работаете в связке с другим языком, например PHP, то можете
   создать .php файл, который меняет в файле (или в базе данных)
   значение какого-то поля настройки с 0 на 1.
2. Установить этот .php файл в crontab на 15:00 каждого дня. Тем самым,
       каждый день этот файл будет менять значение в кешевом файле (или
       базе) с 0 на 1.
3. Далее в node.js циклично, например раз в 5 минут, читайте файл, в
           котором сохранено значение состояния (или с базы).
4. Если значение стало "1" выполните нужный скрипт и поменяйте значение
       обратно в "0"

Comment: А в чём проблема через `cron` выполнять скрипт на `js` через `node`? И зачем же вы сразу про, прости господи, `php`?